# Cocos2d: Positioning Sprites in complex layout patterns

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions for how to manage the positioning of many sprites in pre-set and complicated patterns?  Currently the brute-force method is to painstakingly code each sprite into its place.  However, ideally, I would like to not have to code it directly, but instead read the sprite positions in from a file (or some other data source).  Are there any solutions out there that do this?

Comment: [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19735/how-to-effectively-create-bullet-patterns) may be relevant.

Comment: ya, I guess the answer is no, then.  I was looking for something like the wonderful Tiled or Particle Designer.  Probably an opportunity in the market place to build a tool that does this.  Wouldn't be hard.

Comment: @GregoryJohnson Questions about which technology to use are considered off-topic here. That being said: maybe you should check out [SpriteBuilder](http://www.spritebuilder.com) (formerly CocosBuilder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on iOS using Objective-C, I assume, so use [PLIST](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html) files.

XCode has an excellent PLIST editor. [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) lets you load a PLIST file with a single method call:

```
NSDictionary * plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"test.plist"];
```

From that, it is very easy to automate. Just load the dictionary and set the sprite position:

```
double x = [[plistDict objectForKey:@"sprite_pos_x"] doubleValue];
double y = [[plistDict objectForKey:@"sprite_pos_y"] doubleValue];

sprite.position = ccp(x,y);
```

If you change the sprite position in the PLIST, there is no need to recompile. With a bit of work, you can even add runtime reloading of modified files.

Comment: yes, this is the method I would go with... or actually, JSON would be better, since I would want to have the type of sprite loaded dynamically as well.  As I said above, it's probably really easy to put a GUI around this idea.  Countless side-scrolling games have this concept.  I was looking for a GUI based tool to help put the patterns together... point and click.  Apparently someone out there thinks this is a dumb question tho.  haha... dunno, seems like a good idea to me!